# firebase multiple photo upload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, image-uploading

Has anyone used Firebase to store images since the update? I am working on a site, and I need to give users the ability to create photo albums by uploading multiple photos at once. I was wondering if Firebase would be a good use case for this. And if not, maybe I could get a suggestion on a better solution.

Comment: Yes is a good solution i've been using it to upload multiple images in parallel and in sequence, both scenarios work fine,  the other good alternative would be AWS S3, but if you want an easy and fast way to achieve the functionality Firebase is a good choice